# Как работает приоритет стилей в дочерней теме Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

Если я в дочерней теме сначала импортирую родной стиль

```
(@import url("../twentyten/style.css"))
```

Потом переопределю некоторые элементы - это  будет работать, мои стили перекроют родные?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно. Именно так и работает приоритезация CSS - применяются последние свойства, под селектор которых подходят элементы DOM. (если селекторы равноценны и в свойствах не указано `!important`)